# R: Countrycode package not supporting regex as the origin

Tags: regex, r, country-codes

I have a list of countries that i need to convert into standardized format (iso3c). Some have long names, others have 2 or 3 digit codes, and others do not display the whole country name like "Africa" instead of "South Africa". Ive done some research and come up to use countrycode package in R. However, when i tried to use "regex" R doesnt seem to recognize it. Im getting the error below:

```
> countrycode(data,"regex","iso3c", warn = TRUE)
Error in countrycode(data, "regex", "iso3c",  : 
Origin code not supported
```

Any other option I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: @dixi Please check this link https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode  I am guessing `regex` is not an option here.  Rather it uses the `regex` specified in the `countrycode_data` for the conversion when you use any of the options `cown`, `cowc` etc.

Comment: i see.. i used that document but didnt understand it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the README for the countrycode package here https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode, or you can pull up the help file in R by entering this into your R console `?countrycode::countrycode`.

"regex" is not a valid 'origin' value (2nd argument in the `countrycode()` function). You must use one of "cowc", "cown", "eurostat", "fao", "fips105", "imf", "ioc", "iso2c", "iso3c", "iso3n", "p4_ccode", "p4_scode", "un", "wb", "wb_api2c", "wb_api3c", "wvs", "country.name", "country.name.de" (using latest version 0.19).

If you use either of the following 'origin' values, regex matching will be performed automatically: "country.name" or "country.name.de"

If you're using a custom dictionary with the new (as of version 0.19) `custom_dict` argument, you must set the `origin_regex` argument to `TRUE` for regex matching to occur.

In your example, this should do what you want:
`countrycode(data, origin = "country.name", destination = "iso3c", warn = TRUE)`